# Issue with Python Class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating simple tkinter app using python. My app was working fine but code was mess. Now I am trying to organize my code using class and methods, but facing issue in same
FYI - am new to python
Below is my code.
Logically I have to call tkobject.kky_mnframe_func() before tkobject.frames() as tkobject.kky_mnframe_func() is used as command for one of my tkobject.frames() buttons. But if I do so it is giving error as variable self.ky_entr used in tkobject.kky_mnframe_func() is defined in tkobject.frames() and it need to be called first. So inshort am not able to proceed either way. Any python pro here, who can guide me handle this better way.

```
class TkinterSuperbot:
    def get_git_key(self):
        self.headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'}
        self.login_data = {
            'commit': 'Sign in',
            'utf8': '%E2%9C%93',
            'login': '*******',
            'password': '******'
        }
        with requests.Session() as s:
            self.url = "https://github.com/session"
            self.r = s.get(self.url, headers=self.headers)
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.r.content, 'html.parser')
            self.login_data['authenticity_token'] = self.soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'authenticity_token'})['value']
            r = s.post(self.url, data=self.login_data, headers=self.headers)
        self.json = s.get('https://github.com/*****/****/***/***/***.json')
        self.json.status_code
        self.json_soup = BeautifulSoup(self.json.text, 'html.parser')
        self.key = self.json_soup.find('span', {'class':'pl-c1'}).text
        return self.key

    def kky_mnframe_func(self,event = None): # evevn none is for entery keyboard
        if self.ky_entr.get()==self.get_git_key():
            self.mn_frm.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
            self.ky_frm.forget()
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Access Denied!', 'Invalid Key')

    def frames(self):
        self.window=Tk()
        self.window.geometry('522x300')
        # window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        # Gets the requested values of the height and widht.
        self.windowWidth = self.window.winfo_reqwidth()
        self.windowHeight = self.window.winfo_reqheight()
        print("Width",self.windowWidth,"Height",self.windowHeight)
        # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
        self.positionRight = int(self.window.winfo_screenwidth()/2.45 - self.windowWidth/2)
        self.positionDown = int(self.window.winfo_screenheight()/3 - self.windowHeight/2)
        # Positions the window in the center of the page.
        self.window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(self.positionRight, self.positionDown))
        self.window.iconbitmap('zicon.ico')
        self.window.title('SuperBot')
        self.window.configure(background='light gray')
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.ky_frm = LabelFrame(self.window, text='Enter Authorisation Key', labelanchor='n', pady=0, padx=10, borderwidth=2,background='light gray', font=('arial', 9, 'bold'))
        self.ky_frm.pack(fill='both', expand=1, padx=80, pady=100)
        self.window.bind('<Return>', self.kky_mnframe_func) #for enter key board
        self.ky_entr = Entry(self.ky_frm, show='*', width=21, borderwidth=2, justify=CENTER)
        self.ky_entr.place(x=101, y=10)
        self.ky_bttn = Button(self.ky_frm, text='Submit', background='light gray', font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), width=15, command=self.kky_mnframe_func, cursor='hand2')
        self.ky_bttn.place(x=101, y=40)
        self.ky_bttn.bind('<Return>')
        self.self.mn_frm = Frame(self.window, background='light gray')
        self.label1 = Label(self.self.mn_frm, text='"SuperBot" Welcomes You', font=('arial',18,'bold'), relief='flat', fg='blue2', bg='light gray')
        self.label1.place(x=107, y=240)
        self.button_login= Button(self.mn_frm, text='Login', width=8, font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', fg='white', bg='cornflower blue', command=scrp.linked_login, cursor='hand2')
        self.button_login.place(x=2, y=0)
        self.button_upload = Button(self.mn_frm, text='Upload',width=8, font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', fg='white', bg='cornflower blue', command=scrp.read_links, cursor='hand2')
        self.button_upload.place(x=76, y=0)
        self.button_getprof = Button(self.mn_frm, text='Get',width=8, font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', fg='white', bg='cornflower blue', command=scrp.multi_link_scrpr, cursor='hand2')
        self.button_getprof.place(x=150, y=0)
        self.button_clear = Button(self.mn_frm, text='Clear',width=8, font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', fg='white', bg='cornflower blue', command=scrp.clear_list, cursor='hand2')
        self.button_clear.place(x=224, y=0)
        self.button_download = Button(self.mn_frm, text='Download',width=8, font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', fg='white', bg='cornflower blue', command=scrp.download_profile, cursor='hand2')
        self.button_download.place(x=298, y=0)
        self.button_link = Button(self.mn_frm, text='Links',width=8, font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', fg='white', bg='cornflower blue', command=scrp.group_scroll, cursor='hand2')
        self.button_link.place(x=372, y=0)
        self.button_connect = Button(self.mn_frm, text='Connect',width=8, font=('arial',10,'bold'), relief='raised', fg='white', bg='cornflower blue', command=scrp.group_scroll, cursor='hand2')
        self.button_connect.place(x=446, y=0)
        self.my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('zlogo.png'))
        self.img_label = Label(self.mn_frm,image=self.my_image)
        self.img_label.place(x=157, y=40)
        self.img_label.configure(background='light gray')
        self.window.mainloop()

tkobject = TkinterSuperbot()
tkobject.get_git_key()
tkobject.kky_mnframe_func()
tkobject.frames()
```

Comment: Why does `tkobject.kky_mnframe_func()` need to be executed before `tkobject.frames()`?

Comment: bcoz tkobject.kky_mnframe_func() is used as command for "SUBMIT" button of tkobject.frames()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually CALLING `kky_mnframe_func` in your `frames` function.  You are just passing the function object.  The function won't be called until there's an event on that button, which won't happen until long after `frames` returns.  So, just remove that call from your mainline code.

Comment: removed that call from code but frame is not working. can you please be more explicit